Couldn't roll back CW answer to the version marked "Post Made Community Wiki"
Check out this revision history for a CW answer that a user accidentally edited instead of their own answer: https://mathoverflow.net/posts/391066/revisions and then edited again (with questionable material, yes, but that's not what I'm worried about). I wanted to roll back to the original version of the answer, but there was no button for it. Here's a screenshot of what it looked like at the time

I had to edit the answer manually and copied in the source for v1.
For reference, this answer doesn't follow strict SE protocol, but the user who originally supplied it is working within the framework of MathOverflow norms, so the only thing I need addressed is the technical functionality of the software not working in this case (and not "he shouldn't be using the CW answer functionality like that!").
In the answer to this question I made the answer CW at time of original writing, and the history does give me the chance to roll back to v1


Why did "Post Made Community Wiki" show up as a revision? I reproduced this bug on ELL with different revisions affected: #1 & #2. In contrast, this ELU answer has "Post Made Community Wiki" separately, and I have all the controls as a normal revision, including rollbacks.

Basically what @Laurel said. I have checked some CWs on MO and on my sites, and the normal condition is to have "Post Made Community Wiki" notice as a separate entry, not as a revision.

@Laurel It shows up in the first revision when an answer author didn't make the answer community wiki when initially posting it, but did so in a grace period edit. It can also show up in later revisions if the answer author makes an edit and checks the box at the same time.

@MetaAndrewT. See above.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I see, thanks. Do we have an existing post/bug report about that?

@MetaAndrewT. Couldn't find one. However, I scienced it in two deleted answers here and can confirm what I said appears to be correct.

The answer would have been made CW at the time of answering, so there was no version where the answer was not CW, and a subsequent edit made it CW. Isn't it the case network wide that one can tick the box for a CW while answering?

There is something called the grace period where any edits made within the first five minutes of making a post (for users with 10+ reputation) are merged into the first revision. If the answer author didn't check the box when initially posting but did check the box and submit an edit within said five-minute period, the revision shows up per your screenshot. I just tested now in deleted answers to your question.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I'm aware of the grace period :-) But what happens if one doesn't do it using the grace period?

OK, I see the behaviour now. Screenshot added to the question.

I was, however, able to roll back your answer by clicking the "Edit" button on the earlier revision and not making any changes - this counts as a rollback internally.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks for checking, in case as the poster of the answer was seeing different behaviour.

This is a test answer to check the functionality of CW.
